# UITableView Cell Text AlignmentdetailTextLabel vs textLabel

Tags: uitableview

When using `UITableViewCellStyleValue2`, which label is `detailTextLabel`, and which is the `textLabel`? The small blue text or the larger black text?

I would like my textLabel (black text) to be right aligned, so i have tried this, but with no success.

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight; //tried this just in case, but no luck.
```

Why wont my cells align properly? I am using `UITableViewCellStyleValue2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textLabel` is the larger, blue text, and `detailTextLabel` is the smaller, black text.  `UITableViewCellStyleValue2` sets `textLabel` left-aligned and `detailTextLabel` right-aligned.

You can access the contentView and create subviews to add to it if you want fine-grained control over your styles.